# My itunes library files now start with "original" in the filename. How to fix?

Tags: mp3, itunes, filenames

Not sure what happened, but I think an app I was looking at as an alternative to iTunes at one point, may have hosed my music library.

In trying to clean up and de-dupe my music library, I have found a large number of files (about 1,000) whose filenames now look like this:

original1.07 Triple Concerto.mp3

Whereas they should look like this:

03 Theme For A Mid-Afternoon Game Show.mp3

Don't know WTF happened, and not all of my filenames are messed up like this.  Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix these via some sort of automation?  My library is a combination of stuff from all over the place so I don't have perfectly consistent meta data, ID3 tags, etc.  I'm trying to end up with just one copy of each song on the actual hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up not finding a better solution than using Automater to rename the files where it could, and then the standard Mac search to find all remaining files that began with "original1" and delete them all.  Seems to have done the trick.